# Images getting corrupted when JavaFX Image converted to BufferedImage and back again?

Tags: java, image, io, javafx, arrays

I'm designing a program that stores geography data on the JavaFX platform, and whenever I convert an image from a JavaFX Image into a BufferedImage then a ByteArray (for the purpose of serialization) before converting to a Buffered Image and then JavaFX Image again, it gets slightly corrupt. Here's the code I'm using to convert back and forth:

```
private byte [] loadImageData (Image image){
    try{

        //creating a byte array output stream from the Image           
        BufferedImage bi = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos );


        baos.flush();       
        byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        return imageData;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Image restoreMapData (byte[] data){
    try{
        //converting back to an image
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(in);


        return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could there be an error elsewhere? I've attached a corrupted and un-corrupt picture of the data.[image: corrupted]

[image: uncorrupted]

I also noticed that if I convert to BufferedImage with a type TYPE_INT_ARGB it greatly diminishes the effect.

Comment: Your code makes little sense to a bystander. Whats with the conversion to/from base64? It seems to have no apparent use here. And whats with "serialization" in the title? I don't see any serialization.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was confusing. I made it a little clearer. I also noticed that if I convert to BufferedImage with a type TYPE_INT_ARGB it greatly diminishes the effect.